# React-Native: TextInput not binding to empty string

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I'm building an app for basic "Math Facts" that the student will have 60 seconds to test their addition, multiplication, etc.

When the student enters the correct number of digits (compared with the answer), it will evaluate the answer - score them accordingly, and go on to the next problem automatically `this.props.selectProblem()` just changes the problem and answer - unrelated to input.

The only thing that is not working - is that when the user types in an answer that is a single digit, it does not set the TextInput component to an empty string, but I can set it to any other length of string, just not zero (which is what I need).

Double digit answers work correctly.

I'm confused as to why strings greater than length 0 work, unless the answer is 2 digits.

```
state = {
    userInput: ""
}

handleInput = (text) => {

    this.setState({ userInput: text}, () => {

    let { userInput } = this.state;
    let { answer } = this.props;

    if (userInput.length === answer.toString().length) {

        if (+userInput === +answer) {
            this.setState({ userInput: "" }, () => {
               // add points for correct
            })
        }
        else {
            this.setState({ userInput: "" }, () => {
               // subtract points for incorrect
            });
        }
    this.props.selectProblem();

    }
})
```

And inside render

```
    <TextInput style={styles.input}
               onChangeText={(text) => this.handleInput(text)}
               value={this.state.userInput.toString()}
               maxLength={this.props.answer.length}
    />
```

Comment: Can you verify if the set state is being called when the user enters single digits?

Comment: yes, it definitely is - i have a console log that prints out what was typed, and then an empty string. but the textinput does not clear

Comment: Hmm TextInput has a method to clear text I think, I know for a fact you can use setNativeProps to send a different text value to it. Maybe you can try one of these two methods to clear the text instead of setting an empty string. As to why the code isn't working I'm not too sure because it looks right.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about those. Unfortunately I just tried both, with the same problem. Deletes two digits successfully, but leaves if it's one digit. Function fires regardless. What could it be?

Comment: That definitely is strange. Do you have your code on Github? I could take a proper look

Comment: Thanks for your time @NemiShah, my project has a backend so I just recreated the problem in a basic create-react-native app.
https://github.com/jsarge11/school-test

Comment: @JaySargent were you able to solve this?